# Use .htaccess to load index file from a specific location and url does not exists

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to use  .htaccess to load index file from specific directory when user vitis an url that does not exists.
Here is my folder structure:

```
root/realdirectory/virtualdirectory/virtualproducturl
```

my index file is located in  root/realdirectory

And something else which makes the task more complecated :
 root/realdirectory/index.php has to be loaded if user visits:

```
-root/realdirectory/virtualdirectory/virtualproducturl or 
-root/realdirectory/virtualdirectory/
```

The 'virtualdirectory' is my category of the product and when the user visits just the category url I want to show him some information from root/realdirectory/index.php
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward: when a request does *not* get resolved to an existing file or folder, then internally rewrite it to an "index document":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Working as a charm ! Respect to your knowledge !